# How goes The Guardian make (multi-) coloured notification icons?

Tags: notifications, notification-icons

The election notifications have a red and blue notification icon which remains coloured even in the notification bar (while other icons are monochrome to fit with custom themes).

I thought android no longer allows this? How did the devs go about it?

[image]

[image]